# Select rows from table 1, table 2, then selecting based on ID

Tags: select, teradata

I am dealing with a large dataset, and have run into some issues because of this.

I have a data set like:

Table1

```
    State    ID  Conditional_Value
     AZ       1         Yes
     AZ       2         Yes
     AZ       5         Yes
```

Table 2

```
    State    ID  Conditional_Value
     AZ       1         No
     AZ       3         No 
     AZ       7         No
```

What I need this to return is

```
   State    ID  Conditional_Value
     AZ       1         Yes
     AZ       2         Yes
     AZ       3         No
     AZ       5         Yes
     AZ       7         No
```

If there is a duplicate ID in table 2 take that ID's row from table 1 and select it.

I have tried

```
    Select State, ID, Conditional_Value 
    From Table1
    Union
    Select State, ID, Conditional_Value
    From Table2
    Where Table2.ID not in (select Table1.ID from Table1)
```

But with the large dataset I have, it is too expensive to run.

I have looked at questions about finding duplicates and deleting them and then inserting the non-duplicates into another table, but I need to compare the 2 separate tables as well.

If there is any more info needed, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any index on table1 and table2?

Comment: I could refresh the tables with an index on the ID (which is actually a concatenate value between another id and date) if that helps.

Comment: IMHO it'd help knowing the exactly CREATE TABLE statement, index included.

Comment: I re-built the tables with indexes on a different key (the concatenate value) and it worked in under 7 seconds. Thanks @McNets

Comment: Why do a union when you are manually removing duplicates from the second query? Switching to a union all should help with performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you already seem to have resolved the problem to your satisfaction, the classical solution to this is to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.State, t2.State) as State
      ,COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) as ID
      ,COALESCE(t1.Conditional_Value, t2.Conditional_Value) as Conditional_Value 
  FROM Table1 t1
         FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (    t1.State = t2.State
                                       AND t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

Note: code untested, and I haven't worked with teradata specifically, so there may be some syntax issues I can't predict. However, the basic commands and functions should be correct, from what I can see.

The code merges the two tables based on the `State` and `ID` values. The `COALESCE` functions ensure that whichever table has a value for a particular row, that's the value that will be used. Since we look at `Table1` first, if both `Table1` and `Table2` have a value for `Conditional_Value`, the value from `Table1` will be used.

Comment: thank you - I will give this a run as well - indexing alone worked on a smaller dataset, but when trying to run the larger dataset - I will try the coalesce function. Thanks for your time, everyone.